# Python variables in MySQL execute command

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I've looked for an answer everywhere and didn't manage to find any suitable one.

This is my code:

```
conn = pymysql.Connect(host="host", user="user", passwd="password", db="database")

dbhandler = conn.cursor()
table_name = today_date.split(" ")[0]
execute_it = """CREATE TABLE %s (
        USERNAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
        X CHAR(10), 
        Y INT, 
        Z INT, 
        A INT)"""

try:
    dbhandler.execute(execute_it, table_name)
except:
    print("\n----------------------------\nFailed to create table.")
```

Now I've tried to do it like this.
I tried with % separating in execute.
I tried with ? instead of %s.
I tried it with many more options and yet none of them worked for me and I failed to create the table

This is the exception I get:

> (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''11/14/18' (\n            USERNAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL, \n
>   X CHAR(10' at line 1")

Using 5.5.52-MariaDB.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Managed to get through it.
Thanks Pavel Francírek for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not in placeholder, but in date format. Character "/" is not allowed in table name. Try something like:

```
table_name = today_date.split(" ")[0].replace("/","")
```

I assume that all numbers in your date format are 2-digit.

Comment: By the way I also tried it with                                                                  
"""INSERT INTO table_name (USERNAME, X,Y, Z, A)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %d, %d, %d)""", (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)

Comment: Well, maybe table name must start with letter:
table_name = "t"+today_date.split(" ")[0].replace("/","")

Comment: Usually, there is only one placeholder (%s) and not more like in string format (no %d etc.)

Comment: See the second comment but anyways I tried also what you've said and it didn't work. I'm actually losing my mind here, I tried almost every option and nothing worked...

Comment: You can try to use Python's "".format(). But only if your are absolutely sure about your data source (beware of SQL injection)

Comment: I know %d, but database libraries usually use only %s placeholder. Unlike Python string format.

Comment: the .format() worked for me only on the table name when i try to insert it doesn't work and it looks like this:      """INSERT INTO {} (USERNAME, X,Y, Z, A)
            VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {})""".format(table_name, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)